# Three js loaded objects are pixelated (not having a high finishing)

Tags: three.js, rendering, blender

When I load objects to Three.Js (.obj or .js), the edges are not rendered perfectly.
It is shown with pixilated edges (not having a high finish or sharp edges).

I tried both THREE.JSONLoader() and THREE.OBJLoader() and it gives me the same results.

I opened these objects with Blender to see how it looks like when using Blender renderer. Blender renderer shows a high finished and sharp edges as expected.

The following links contain a picture and a video to give more information about my problem.
In the video, the upper edges can explain the problem.

[Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rf4My1LHiQdwP7YGEovBPC8STOjh0n0x/view?usp=sharing),  [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cQyWzGxP5ZnIbkmij9BR6nhEGOLc74ca/view?usp=sharing)

My Question is how to remove pixelation and having sharp edges for objects loaded on Three js?

Comment: See also: [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing).

Comment: With that it makes it easier to find possible duplicates, eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113835/anti-aliasing-three-js-webgl , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554969/dynamically-turn-on-off-antialiasing-and-shadows-in-webglrenderer , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205339/threejs-ssao-with-ssaa

Comment: Thanks, @user2864740 you put me on the right track. The second answer in this question helps a lot in solving the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224795/antialiasing-not-working-in-three-js

Comment: @user2864740 Can you please post the answer to mark it as a solution to help others to get the solution quickly?